# Error "Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00"

Tags: jpeg, photo, corruption

I am trying to open the photos of my trip made with the camera eken 4k and half of the photos give the error:

> Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00

The other half if they look. I have tried to change to extension png and similar and to open it with another program. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe it is a RAW file?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Are you going to reply to my message?

Comment: Can you share some of the damaged files?